# Buscar id em array de objetos com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, possuo o seguinte array de objetos:

```
[
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Javascript"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Como eu poderia filtrar esse objeto e retornar somente os developers que possuem, por exemplo, a technology com id 6.
O retorno que preciso são somente os developers que possuem relação com a technology id 6, porém, preciso que apareçam também as outras technologies atreladas ao developer.

Sei que através do metodo find, é possível fazer isso, mas não sei como implementar.

```
const result = developers.find(dev => dev.technologies ?);
```

Qual seria a forma correta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) retorna somente o primeiro elemento que for encontrado. Mas como o resultado pode ter mais de um, uma alternativa é usar [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

E como o critério é "uma das tecnologias deve ter id 6", basta usar `find` para buscar dentro das tecnologias de cada developer:

```js
let developers = [
  { "id": 97, "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      { "id": 6, "name": "React" },
      { "id": 7, "name": "Messageria" }
    ]
  },
  { "id": 98, "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      { "id": 2, "name": "Javascript" },
      { "id": 6, "name": "React" }
    ]
  },
  { "id": 99, "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      { "id": 8, "name": "PHP" },
      { "id": 9, "name": "Laravel" }
    ]
  }
];

let result = developers.filter(dev => dev.technologies.find(t => t.id == 6));
console.log(result);
```

O `filter` retorna os elementos para os quais a condição é verdadeira.

Se `find` não encontra nada, é retornado `undefined` (que é avaliado como "falso"), e se encontra alguma coisa, retorna o respectivo elemento (e qualquer objeto não nulo é considerado "verdadeiro").

Assim, se a busca por `technologies` encontrar um elemento com `id` igual a 6, o respectivo `dev` é retornado por `filter`.

Outra boa alternativa é usar [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) em vez de `find` para fazer a busca em `technologies`, conforme indicado por [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471832/112052).

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer isso usando o `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Basicamente, precisa de uma expressão booleanda que retorne true/false pra selecioar um elemento do array, veja o exemplo:

```js
var dados = [
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Javascript"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var x = dados.filter(d => d.technologies.some(tec => tec.id == 6));
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Boa, tinha esquecido do `some` :-)

Answer (score 4):

Como `technologies` é um array, tens que iterar sobre o array e ver se existe algum objecto com o `id` que pretendes.
Por exemplo:

```js
developers.find(dev => {
    let hasReact = false;
    dev.technologies.forEach(tech => {
        if (tech.id == 6) {
            hasReact = true;
        }
    });
    return hasReact;
});
```

Atenção que o `find` encontra apenas o primeiro. Se quiseres todos usa `filter`.

```js
developers.filter(dev => {
    let hasReact = false;
    dev.technologies.forEach(tech => {
        if (tech.id == 6) {
            hasReact = true;
        }
    });
    return hasReact;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, esta é a minha primeira contribuição. É mais verbosa que a contribuição de **hkotsubo**, porém se adaptada pode servir para diversos outros propósitos que talvez o uso do filter e find não consigam realizar. Segue!

```js
const developers = [
    {
        "id": 97, "name": "Jon",
        "technologies": [
            { "id": 6, "name": "React" },
            { "id": 7, "name": "Messageria" },
            { "id": 9, "name": "Laravel" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 98, "name": "Doe",
        "technologies": [
            { "id": 2, "name": "Javascript" },
            { "id": 6, "name": "React" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 99, "name": "Mark",
        "technologies": [
            { "id": 8, "name": "PHP" },
            { "id": 9, "name": "Laravel" }
        ]
    }
];

const tecInf = 6;

function encontrarDevs(tecInf, developers) {
    const devsTecInf = [];
    const qtdDev = developers.length;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < qtdDev; i++) {
        const qtdTec = developers[i].technologies.length;
        for (let j = 0; j < qtdTec; j++) {
            if (developers[i].technologies[j].id === tecInf) {
                devsTecInf.push(developers[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return devsTecInf;
}

console.log(encontrarDevs(tecInf, developers));
```